# How to make a TextBox fillout the entire Grid Cell in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8

Here is my current code and I am not happy with the result. For some reason  the `TextBox` control does not fillout the entire GridCell. The boxes are tiny and ive tryed setting the width/height of the textBox to get them bigger, but then it doesnt work at all. I have also tryed setting the alignment to stretch, but that didnt help either. Any tips/advice on how I could maybe get this working would be appreciated.

```
//create the grid
        Grid backGrid = new Grid();
        backGrid.Width = 380;
        backGrid.Height = 200;
        backGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        backGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        backGrid.ShowGridLines = false;

        //define columns
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
            backGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
        }

        //define rows
        for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
        {
            RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
            backGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);
        }

        //create textboxes
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
            {

                TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                txtBox.FontSize = 16;
                txtBox.Margin = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                txtBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

                txtBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                Grid.SetRow(txtBox, r);
                Grid.SetColumn(txtBox, c);

                backGrid.Children.Add(txtBox);
            }
        }

        //add the grid into the mainpage
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(backGrid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's default `TextBox Margin`. It's described in `TextBox Template`

The following XAML shows the default style and template for the `TextBox` [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
Style TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
  <Setter.Value>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
      <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF99C1E2" Duration="0"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
          </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
          <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
          </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
          <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                      <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                  </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </vsm:VisualState>
          </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
            <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Opacity="0" Background="#5EC9C9C9"/>
            <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
              <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
            </Border>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Background="#A5F7F7F7" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
          <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" 
                     PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
              <ToolTip.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                  <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                              <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                  </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
              </ToolTip.Triggers>
            </ToolTip>
          </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
          <Grid Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
            <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
            <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You need to create new style for `TextBox` (in Expression Blend right click on `TextBox`-> EditTemplate-> Esit a Copy ) and modify it however you want. 
 For removing default margin use this style

```
<Style x:Key="NewTextBoxStyleWithoutMargins" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I just replace `Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}"` to `Margin="0"`.

Just set this style to your `TextBox`. 
Hope it's help.